# Cannot change og_type

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I just replaced a tumblr website for a client with a brand new Wordpress site. And when running it through the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), I get this error:

> The object at 'http://example.com/' previously had type 'tumblr-feed:tumblelog' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.

I Googled "Cannot change og_type" (in quotes) and got literally zero [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot%20change%20og_type#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Cannot%20change%20og_type%22&oq=%22Cannot%20change%20og_type%22&fp=b2b10486a813a4e7) (well now it seems there are results stemming from this question). Am I really doomed to Facebook data mismatch?

Comment: I have the same issue when switching from blogengine.net to Wordpress ... been googling for hours, and none of the WP plugins seem to work.  If I find an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - and this is the only place on the Internet that I could find someone having the same issue. I accidently copied code over and put a 'movie' type in for a page that was supposed to be 'website'. Now Debugger has og_type locked to 'movie' and won't let me change it. The page being linked only has ~190 'likes' or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the error message

`... cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.`

If the `og:type` were changed for a URL, any existing user posts linking to it or sharing it, any Open Graph actions referencing it, as well as any likes of the URL would become broken and the user's profiles would be missing content they'd posted before.

I don't believe there's any way around this, as it's an intentional restriction to avoid breaking existing posts, likes, actions, etc referencing a URL. If the posts were broken, content would be removed from or mangled on the user's timeline.

A possible workaround if you want to have a 'new' object at that URL is to use my instructions in [this answer about moving URLs](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10152342/21062) to put a Like button on the URL you're trying to change (let's call it A), but pointing to a slightly different, new URL (let's call it B) , and then use the redirect mechanism in my answer to bounce users landing at URL B back to A, but serve the metdata describing 'A' on URL B if the Facebook crawler accesses it

Comment: Hmm... seems like a potential workaround, but is there a reliable way to determine the identity of the Facebook crawler? And essentially, I would need to create a new URL to point back to my old one (eg example.com/facebooklanding.html)

Comment: Yes, correct, the workaround seems more reasonable the context of OG objects or article URLs, and less so when you're talking about the root URL of a domain with a like button, but it's the same system and same code on the backend - the facebook crawler has a known user agent header, currently `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` which you could use to identify the requests from FB

Comment: Not that I'm disputing your answer, but this seems like incredibly bad design on facebook's part. Under no circumstances should Facebook be dictating what my web page content should be

Comment: It's not dictating your web page's content, it's dictating that once actions have been posted to Facebook about a URL, some aspects of Facebook's metadata for that URL cannot be change to prevent the previous actions from being corrupted

Answer (score 1):

Does the client's site have more than 10,000 likes? If so, Facebook doesn't allow `og:type` to be changed.

> You can update the attributes of your page by updating your page's  tags. Note that og:title and og:type are only editable initially - after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed, and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed. These properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked the page already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits are reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and type.

[Here's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) the link to the **Open Graph** documentation. :)

Comment: Nope, ~600 likes on the Facebook page, and none on the domain itself (example.com). I'll peruse the docs some more in a bit, here

Comment: This is quite an illusive issue, I see.

Comment: I believe that documentation is for the old, April 2010 stuff, and it's since been changed - i'll see if we can get it updated, but i think there should be a note saying that it's possibly out of date

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using the Open Graph Debugger to check what facebook really sees and if facebook eventually has a cached version of your site. (you find hte debugger here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: I said right in the question that the problem is displayed in the debugger... Thanks anyway, though!

Comment: I am sorry, after some many hours of coding I have overread that bit - shame on me!. 

What happens if you keep "tumblr-feed:tumblelog" as og:type?

Answer (score -1):

NOte that it doesnt say og:type - it says og_type

This is hitting me too since my og:type is set to "shamrockirishbar:shamrockirishbar" BUT the linter is saying og_type (of which there is none in my meta data) is set to "website".
[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.shamrockirishbar.com)