# Facebook doesn't allow me to chage the og:type for my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm setting up a temporary *coming soon* one-pager for my employer and after running the [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) on it, as I usually do when setting up a new site it brings up an error I've not seen before.

> **Cannot change og_type** The object at 'http://www.example.com/' previously had type 'article' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.

So, the graph API still returns the old OGP data for the URL (https://graph.facebook.com/10150291357906791) even though I've changed the meta tags on the website.

The url has 15 likes already, and honestly, I don't really care that much about them and if the solution involves losing them, I'm all for it.

I found a solution for changing the `og:type` for subpages (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/14405329/859999), but the page in this case is the root of the website. So… the solution posted there is not usable in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot change og\_type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343288/cannot-change-og-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don’t care about existing likes, I’d suggest to just use a new URL for this.

You said it is the root URL of your page – but if it’s only temporary, you could redirect from there to another address (which has the correct meta info).

(If you are worried about your SEO-Ranking or something, you could do this redirect only for the Facebook scraper, recognizing it by its User Agent.)